# Inline editing problems

Tags: bug, status-completed, inline-editor, internet-explorer-9

Inline editing seems a bit broken at the time, at least in IE 9:

```
SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation. 
wmd.js?v=5f7bc6eb2343, line 1 character 44242
```

is what the console tells me. Results are that the preview doesn't work and that the accelerator keys for the toolbar (which appears to be gone?) don't work anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed now.

This is an age-old IE problem that seemingly has still not been fixed in IE 9: You cannot set the `innerHTML` value of an element that is contained somewhere in a table.

So far, our editor was *not* contained in a table, but with the new inline editing it is; that's why this hasn't come up before.

So if the browser doesn't like to go the simple route, we now detach the element from the DOM, set the content, and reattach it. Which, by the way, feels like an utterly ridiculous thing to do :)

Comment: This seems to be the corresponding Connect entry: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/678342

Comment: Do you have an example of how you did this by chance, or could you make a quick one?

Answer (score 0):

I can also offer this advice:

If you're using JQuery, then you can sidestep this problem by using:

`.html()`

While I've not delved into the guts of the JQuery code, this seems to have implemented the necessary workarounds, and its use is almost the same in most cases.

Comment: The editor is open source without a jQuery dependency, so we can't use  jQuery there. http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/